# Excel 2010 Redim Preserve crash

Tags: vba, excel

I am somehow able to crash Excel 2010 by entering the following into the IDE in a brand new workbook:

```
private sub foo
    redim v(,1 to 3)
```

OK, you're not likely to type that ... but here's what really happened:

```
private sub foo
    dim v(1 to N, 1 to M)
    ...
    M = New_Value
    redim preserve v(,1 to M)  ' seemed reasonable ... then CRASH !!!
```

It's funny that VBA requires that you be explicit with the 1st param of a 2D redim preserve (in that you're not allowed to alter the 1st dimension).  But it's not funny when the penalty for a simple syntax error is a hard crash.  This is an IT dept with a reasonably clean environment (no installed addins, starting w empty project pane in IDE), and "redim v(,1 to M)" crashed my neighbor's machine too - so it's not just me.

I am wondering if this behavior occurs with others, and am posting it just in case it saves someone else the hours I wasted rebuilding my workbooks until I pinned down the bug.

Comment: That is fun. I just pasted your sample #2 into a new Excel module and the whole thing fell apart! Maybe if enough of us sent this, someone will fix it :)

Comment: Yes it caused a crash for me as well.  Excel 2010.

Comment: @Remou, sent to who? as far as I know there is no bug report for Excel.  Certainly not on the microsoft connect site.  http://weblog.timaltman.com/archive/2006/03/22/reporting-bugs-microsoft

Comment: @Reafidy on my PC, when an MS program crashes, it asks me if I wish to send a report to Microsoft.

Comment: @Remou, I dont get that option. I wonder were that report goes anyway - filing cabinet in the bottom of a locked basement most probably.  I was referring more to something like the connect website where other users can also flag it and you can track the bug and actually get a response from MS.

Comment: @Reafidy Oh I think if a bucket of reports arrive for the same problem, something will happen.

Comment: @Remou, you certainly have more faith than me!  It wasn't an option for me though, did you manage to send it?

Comment: @Reafidy I pretty much always send. Here are some notes on MS error reporting http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/turn-on-windows-7-send-error-report-option/7ede4f29-a45a-44cf-aeb5-bf43fa7d3c57

Comment: @Reafidy: You can file bugs for Excel. I usually do it from https://connect.microsoft.com/site470/SearchResults.aspx?SearchQuery=excel

Comment: BTW, I just filed the above bug from MVP Connect Services.

Comment: @Sidd, I was going off this link [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/Connect/feedback/details/652240/office-2010-is-not-available-for-bug-reports) Can you provide the link for the bug you posted?

Comment: If you click the above link you can see it there. :)

Comment: I clicked the standard "send rpt to MS" button after the crash, but otherwise don't know how to inform MS.  Thanks for the assistance above.

Comment: The bug also exists in Excel 2003.  So it appears this is the first time in 10 years that anyone has tried to omit the first dimension from a Redim statement.  BTW you have declared `v` as a fixed array not a dynamic array.  I do not recall ever trying but I thought it was not possible to redim a fixed array.

Comment: you're right, so my example illustrating the bug has its own bug, v should be a variant redim'd to a 2d array

Comment: @Sidd, The link you mentioned just brings up a product search results page with 0 results.  Is it just an MVP thing?

Comment: Crashes my 2016 too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The crash occurs from both the omission of the first dimension, or perhaps better phrased, an omission at *nLastDimension - 1*, and also use of the TO keyword in the following dimension.

I took your small sample and tried to make it NOT crash :P

```
Option Explicit 'Just wanted to make the Interpreter more picky

Private Sub test()
    'Go through some basic declaration
    Dim v() As Variant
    Dim M As Integer
    Dim New_Value As Integer

    ReDim v(2, 2) 'No Problem
    ReDim Preserve v(1, 1 To M) ' No Problem
    ReDim Preserve v(1 To M) ' No Problem
    ReDim Preserve v(,400) 'Compile Error

    'Crash on this
    'ReDim Preserve v(,1 To M) 'BOOM!!!
    'and this:
    'ReDim Preserve v(,1 To 2) 'BOOM!!!
    'and this:
   'ReDim Preserve v(1 to 5,,1 To 2) 'BOOM!!!


End Sub
```

Bottom line, none of the code before the "BOOM" lines will cushion the fall.  A compiler error I would understand, but VBA is not coded to handle

```
ReDim myVar(,x TO y)
```

I used Office 2007.

---

For kicks and grins, I also tried this code in the following places:

1. Access '97 (CRASH)
2. Visual Basic 5 IDE (CRASH)
3. BASIC environment for OpenOffice Calc. (See below)

It did not crash and I received the following two compiler errors:
First this:
[image]

Then this:

[image]

Comment: When did VBA go boom on your errors?  In tpascale's post he says: "... the hours I wasted rebuilding my workbooks until I pinned down the bug."  With Excel 2003, it booms (1) when I press return if I type in the faulty line or (2) when I move off line with up, down or mouse after removing the first dimension from a previously correct line.  Even without tpascale's help I would have known what I did to crash Excel if not on the first attempt then when I tried to re-enter my changes.  Are Excel 2007 and 2010 different?

Comment: @TonyDallimore for me it happens on both 1 and 2 for all Crash scenarios.  I also tried importing the crash code and Office crashes on the import.  I'm not sure about tpascale's scenario that caused such a dramatic loss of work.

Comment: To clarify ... there was loss of time, not work.  I save often enough not to lose work on crashes, but in the old days bloated wb crashes were a common occurrence and the remedy taught to me was to export all the IDE modules & recreate the wb from scratch using cell copies but not sheet copies.  I don't know whether this practice can be dropped in 2010, but after a couple of crashes I tried that as a remedy - waste of time.

Comment: Thanks Ray for digging in even further ... accepting the answer for all that work.