# What VBA code can I write that will guarantee a "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" error message?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this seems like a strange question, but one of my clients is having problems with Excel randomly crashing and giving the error message "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" (Problem Event Name: APPCRASH) while my C# program is using Excel (invisibly), and I'm trying to duplicate the problem so I can figure out a way for my program to handle an Excel crash. So I need some VBA code that will cause Excel to crash with the APPCRASH event. I tried the below, but it won't cause a crash unless Excel is visible. Any suggestions?

```
Do
   x = 1
Loop
```

Here is the error message:
[image]

Comment: The error message "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" is not caused by one single fault. There are many reasons this can happen, APPCRASH is just a collection of those causes. Thus it's futile to try to simulate an event that can have multiple causes. You need to investigate the cause on the very computer.

Comment: Replace `x = 1` with `Application.Calculate`.

Comment: Any in-process C# code that throws an unhandled exception can get you an APPCRASH event. Are you sure you're looking at it from the right end? How would crashing the host from VBA code relate to the problem in any way, let alone help diagnose anything? What's that code doing? Questions saying "I need code that does X" typically don't tend to be a good fit for this site.

Comment: [Crash Excel with a ReDim statement](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8931056/1188513)

Comment: You really need to take this from the C# side of things. I voted to close this question last week, and after all this time my vote still stands: this is VERY likely caused by an exception in your C# code, and we've still seen none of it, and you still haven't clarified whether you're spawning the EXCEL.EXE process or if you're running in-process. You need to reproduce the user crash with the Visual Studio debugger running; I'm 99.999% sure that'll break on an unhandled exception. Getting random VBA code that crashes Excel is amusing, but competely useless.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - could you explain why you think this is caused in the C# code? If the exception is in the C# code, why would Excel crash and the C# program continue running without a hitch? The C# code is dropping some data into an Excel spreadsheet, and the VBA manipulates and displays the data.

Comment: Believe it or not, we're actually trying to help. The question asked is "what VBA code could possibly crash Excel like this", and the answer is "C#/COM interop code can do that". I'm *moving on* now. Good luck.

Comment: How is your program interacting with Excel? Based on the WER report, that looks suspiciously like the error you get when something had `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject` called on it that shouldn't have.

Comment: @Comintern - using interop. It opens the workbook, drops the data in, and calls the VBA method. I will take a look at that.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - Your last comment actually made more sense to me. Thank you for the help. Sorry for getting testy.

Answer (score 9):

Stick your hands in its stuff, twist them around, grab something soft and squishy, and then rip it out.

This should do the trick:

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SetWindowLong Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowLongA" _
  (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nIndex As Long, ByVal dwNewLong As Long) As Long

Private Const GWL_WNDPROC As Long = (-4)

'SAVE YOUR WORK!
Private Sub BuhBye()
    Dim hWnd As Long
    hWnd = FindWindow(vbNullString, Application.Caption)
    SetWindowLong hWnd, GWL_WNDPROC, AddressOf OopsIDivedItAgain
End Sub

Public Function OopsIDivedItAgain(ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal Msg As Long, _
    ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Long) As Long
    OopsIDivedItAgain = 1 / 0
End Function
```

It basically subclasses the main Excel window and intentionally throws from inside the message pump.

Comment: Damn you're evil.

Comment: FWIW `Application.hWnd` could be used to eliminate the `hWnd` local variable and `FindWindow` API call.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon True (completely spaced that), although if you want to crash *Word* from Excel...  Muahahaha!

Comment: Haha. That definitely crashes Excel. But I don't get the same error and response from my program that the customer is experiencing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MatthewHagemann I'm not exactly sure what you were expecting as an answer then. The question "crash Excel in exactly the same way that it crashes on a user's machine so I can figure out why it crashes" is oddly specific (and would require a little more omniscience than most of us on SO have).

Comment: The goal is to produce the "Microsoft Excel has stopped working" APPCRASH. That is what we've been unable to achieve. The proposed solution just kills the app without producing APPCRASH with the error message. I don't know enough about the inner-workings to know why this is the case, which is why I'm looking for help.

Comment: @MatthewHagemann Can you edit your question to include the WER report that you're looking for then?

Comment: @MatthewHagemann OK, silly question. I checked my event log and found the application error events triggered by this code: "Faulting application name: EXCEL.EXE, version: 15.0.5093.1000, time stamp: 0x5bed2d14
Faulting module name: VBE7.DLL, version: 7.1.10.68, time stamp: 0x58def2a6".  Is it possible that you just don't have WER configured to log them?

Comment: @Comintern - I added the screenshot of the error. I've never configured WER before. I'll look into that.

Answer (score 7):

This is very likely an X-Y problem.

The way to fix the issue isn't to figure out some random VBA code that gets you a similar APPCRASH event log entry - none will. Or if any does, then you're not going to learn anything new anyway.

The way to fix the problem is to attach the VS debugger to the EXCEL.EXE process, reproduce user steps, then watch VS break on an unhandled exception in the C# code.

Most likely you're getting a `COMException` somewhere, your Excel instance suddenly dies as a result, and writes an APPCRASH that's a side-effect of an exception that occurred out-of-process, in the managed code that spawned the EXCEL.EXE process.

Make sure your C# code correctly releases all COM objects it's accessing (that's every single `Worksheet`, `Range` /cells, `Worksheets` collections, `Application` instance), and isn't chaining object member calls (resulting in a memory leak), e.g.:

```
xlApp.Worksheets("foo").Range("A1").Value = 42;
```

The above is leaking the `Worksheets` collection, the `Worksheet` instance, and the `Range` for the accessed cell.

Managed and COM threading models aren't exactly compatible either, so if your C# code is accessing COM objects from multiple threads, expect `COMException` galore.

---

The first thing to do is reproduce the problem with a debugger attached, and see if your C# code is throwing an exception. Trying to find some VBA code that will crash Excel isn't going to help with anything.